# Fan-fic where Harry and Draco are soulmates?

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, drarry

I don't remember exactly where I read it. (Fanfiction.net or Ao3)

Harry and Draco have a kindred soul relationship. They have known each other since they were children and their families are aware of the relationship between them.
Draco doesn't much care about his relationship with Harry, preferring to spend his time with other people (Blaise or Pansy).

I remember a scene where, on Draco's birthday, Harry goes to his house to give him a present, but Draco isn't there. When Draco arrives, the adults in the room know that he was late because he was with someone else (Remus smells it, that the other person's scent is on Draco, enough to know it wasn't because he was just having a conversation with the other person).

Later Draco is in the kitchen making out with Pansy (I think) and Harry sees them as he goes to get a glass of water, drops the glass and runs off to Grimmauld Place (hides in the library and doesn't want to talk to anyone).
I think Draco didn't mind the relationship because he felt they were too young to settle down.